# Xcode 4: Custom TableViewController .m file cannot be edited. At all. The content disappears.

Tags: xcode, uitableview, osx-mavericks

So this is just bizarre. If I create a custom Table View Controller as a subclass of `UITableViewController`, I can't reliably edit the `.m file`. When I click on it, I can see everything in the file, but I can't actually drop the cursor in to edit the code; it stays fixed in the top-left of the screen. Anything I type will appear, and any code already in `.m` that happens to be on that line will randomly appear. It's like a static image of the `.m` contents are on the screen, but the actual text is hidden.

Eventually the entire editor just goes blank. Everything else works fine. I wiped `Xcode` with app cleaner to pick up all the loose com files, restarted, re-installed `Xcode` from the `dmg` and re-created the project and still have the same problem (this is under Mavericks, by the way).

Granted, `Xcode 5` doesn't seem to have this issue, but I'm quite new to programming and am following a course that's based on `Xcode 4`. And at this point the issue is just so stupidly weird that I want to figure out what's going wrong. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

I've given up. If for some strange reason someone happens on this question and has the same problem, it's not worth the energy; just head to Xcode 5 and live your life bizarre-error free (for now, heh).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I just cleaned the Build Folder and everything seems to be working perfectly now.  You clean the build folder by selecting Product, hold Alt, and then "Clean Build Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem after upgrading to XCode 5, then downloading and installing XCode 4.5 (without removing Xcode 5).  What I wound up doing was to create all my new UITableViewController files (File->New File->Objective C Class) as UIViewController files, then modifying the parent class to UITableViewController in the .h file.